# Error with GetChildNamed("xxxx")

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, marmalade, marmalade-iwui

I'm playing with IwUI RSS sdk sample. I made a change of adding a link label to feed page (2nd page). I made this change by copying the description CIwUILabel block and renaming it to say 'linkLabel' and accordingly added that as an element to the CIwUIElement 'Lables' just below Title element. This works fine in x86 marmalade emulator, GCC ARM Debug emulator.

But when I take this to BlackBerry device, it breaks with the error - "Element '' does not have child with name 'linkLabel'. Why it is saying element ''?

Does it mean that my edits in IwUIItems.ui are not getting into device build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody stumbles on this, please find the details below - 
As @Creator said, my changes did not get into the deployment package but the reason it was running fine in the Marmalade simulator does not allow to believe this. The reason was that the changes were getting in the .bin file correctly. But the deploy tool was looking for that file in data folder. There was an old file available and that was getting into my deployment package.

So I have to copy .group.bin file from **data-ram\data-gles1** to **data** folder after running the application in x86 debug mode. Then build the deployment package for BlackBerry 10

For WP8, we have to copy .group.bin file form **data-ram\gles2-dx11** to **data** folder.

Comment: Or you can just point your asset folder to data-ram for GCC builds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your changes didn't get included in the .bin file. The .group file or .ui file doesn't get included in the GCC build, you need the corresponding .bin file, which you'll get after loading the .group file in x86 simulator.

Just delete the data-ram folder, clean your project, re-run the x86 simulator, make sure UI.group gets loaded before you quit.

optionally you can even delete the VS project folder to get a perfectly clean build. Double clicking on mkb will recreate the project again.

Comment: Yes, @Creator you were almost there. I solved it. Thanks! anyways.